# String changes after function call

Tags: c++

I'm probably making a very obvious mistake, but I just can't see it and I'm hoping somebody can help me.

I want to add 2 strings into a vector of pairs in my C++ program. The container looks like `vector< pair < word , type > > vec`. Where the word can be anything and the type is a noun, adjective, verb, and so forth. For example `< Hogwarts , noun>`, `< Hungry, adjective>`, and so on.

Here's where I add the words to the word bank. FileStrings is just another container created from File I/O. Everything is fine here.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < fileStrings.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << "Adding " << fileStrings[i] << ", " << fileStrings[i + 1] << endl;
    theWordBank.addWord(fileStrings[i], fileStrings[++i]);
}
```

Here's where I get lost. When newWord is printed out it is exactly the same as newType. I can't make sense of it and I don't understand how newWord lost its value from the code snippet above.

```
void addWord(const string& newWord, const string& newType)
{
    mWords.push_back(make_pair(newWord, newType));
    std::cout << "newWord " << newWord << ", " << newType << std::endl;
}
```

Once again, the result should be something like `< Hogwarts, noun>`, but instead I get `< noun, noun>` for everything in the mWords vector of pairs. I don't think it even has anything with mWords. Is my assignment list for the addWord function doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely your problem:

```
theWordBank.addWord(fileStrings[i], fileStrings[++i]);
```

It is *undefined behaviour* to use `i` more than once in an expression where you also use `++i` (or other increment/decrement operator). Do this instead:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < fileStrings.size(); i += 2)
    theWordBank.addWord(fileStrings[i], fileStrings[i + 1]);
}
```

There will be absolutely no discernible difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I would've kept modifying my vector because I assumed the problem was inside addWords(). I changed it to i + 1 and changed the iterator in the for loop to i = i + 2.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Are you sure that that description is accurate?  I thought that `fileStrings[i]` and `fileStrings[++i]` were considered separate expressions.

Comment: @nix: They are each expressions in their own right, but the whole line is *also* an expression that calls a method.

Answer (score 1):

There are further issues with your code.  You are accessing an element out of bounds of the vector in your `cout`.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < fileStrings.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << "Adding " << fileStrings[i] << ", " << fileStrings[i + 1] << endl;
```

Assume that fileStrings contains 1 item.  The `fileStrings[i+1]` would attempt to access `fileStrings[1]` ,which is an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't think of that. The way my external file is set up that shouldn't be a problem, but I should modify it to avoid any future issues.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the order that function parameters are evaluated is undefined.  It's entirely possible that in your implementation, the second parameter in `theWordBank.addWord(fileStrings[i], fileStrings[++i]);` is evaluated before the first.

Note that you should not rely on this; your compiler is free to do whatever it wants when you invoke undefined behaviour.  It may not behave consistently.  It may seem to work now, then fail mysteriously with a different compiler version.  Change it to something that doesn't depend on the order of parameter evaluation, such as

```
theWordBank.addWord(fileStrings[i], fileStrings[i+1]);
++i;
```

Comment: Interesting, I guess I assumed the params were evaluated left to right. That's good to know!